# RangeError: Invalid string length at Array.join

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-chrome

I'm trying to generate a string by joining large array.  But has be gotten :

RangeError: Invalid string length at Array.join

This error occurs in ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍Chrome, in Firefox, no problem.
‍‍‍‍‍‍

```
    function ensureString( buffer ) {

            if ( typeof buffer !== 'string' ) {

                var uint8 = new Uint8Array( buffer );

                const limit = 50000000;

                console.log( uint8.length ); // 621757404

                if ( uint8.length > limit ) {

                    var end = 0;
                    var decodedText = [];

                    for ( let start = 0; start < uint8.length; start = end + 1 ) {

                        end = start + limit;

                        decodedText.push( new TextDecoder().decode( uint8.slice( start, end ) ) );


                    }

                    return decodeText.join( '' );

                }

                return new TextDecoder().decode( uint8 );

            }

            return buffer;

        }
```

Comment: You are (probably) generating a really long long long string. You are generating an string longer than V8 supports.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The size of the read file is more than `600 MB`.

Comment: decodedText.push is not a function (because decodedText is initialized as a string).

Comment: It was a typo that was corrected. tanks